# native base height content

Tags: react-native, native-base

I have code for render:

```
    <ScrollView>
        <Tabs
          style={styles.tabs}
          tabBarUnderlineStyle={styles.tabs_underline}
          initialPage={0}
        >
          <Tab
            tabStyle={styles.tab}
            textStyle={styles.tab_text}
            activeTabStyle={styles.tab}
            activeTextStyle={styles.tab_text}
            heading="First tab"
          >
            <Content style={styles.content_login}>
            ...
            </Content>
          </Tab>
          <Tab
            tabStyle={styles.tab}
            textStyle={styles.tab_text}
            activeTabStyle={styles.tab}
            activeTextStyle={styles.tab_text}
            heading="Second tab"
          >
            <Content style={styles.content_login}>
            ...
            </Content>
          </Tab>
        </Tabs>
    </ScrollView>
```

And I want normal height in the content. Problem in screenshots for example:

at first:
[image]

later:
[image]

and:
[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: can you provide me the code of 'styles.content_login'....!!

Comment: @chetangodiya `content_login: {
    alignSelf: "center",
    paddingTop: 10,
    paddingBottom: 10,
    width: "90%"
  }`

Comment: No need to add scroll view in native base anything inside content tag will be automatically converted into scroll view

Comment: try to get of height of Dimension and apply it to the style 'content_login'

Comment: @chetangodiya doesn't work :(